# Axlsx Rails. Generate .xlsx file and respond filename as json/html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, export-to-excel, axlsx

I am generating xlsx files with axlsx_rails gem.

After collecting user input I am posting data to `/basic_report_post.xlsx`

Controller action looks like

```
def basic_report_post
    @config = params[:config]
    @data = params[:data]
    @filename = "#{Rails.root}/public/test.xlsx"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx {
        render xlsx: 'basic_report_post'
      }
    end
  end
```

View file for this action basic_report_post.xlsx.axlsx

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook    
wb.add_worksheet(name: 'Data1') do |s|    
# Drawing columns    
end
xlsx_package.serialize @filename
```

My problem is that I am getting response data(in post success action) that is raw .xlsx file.
But I need somehow respond `@filename` (format json/html) to download it after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use the `axlsx_rails` template renderer to create a string and save it to file:

```
def basic_report_post
  @config = params[:config]
  @data = params[:data]
  @filename = "#{Rails.root}/public/test.xlsx"
  File.open(@filename, 'w') do |f|
    f.write render_to_string(handlers: [:axlsx], formats: [:xlsx], template: 'path/to/template')
  end
  render json: {name: @filename}
end
```

Then you can use the template to serve the file directly if need be.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My solution works as well but I am marking this as right answer, cause working with templates is more preferable way for me then a  lot of helper functions. I have a lot of sheets so I will keep each of them in a separate partial/template.

Comment: hi @noel hi there - i'm getting this error in rspec: `ActionController::UnknownFormat:` . any ideas?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Can you create an issue on github with more detail? There are a few issues there on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments with `respond_to` I move .xlsx generation logic to view helper.

So I have included `BasicReportHelper` in controller.

basic_report_helper.rb

```
module BasicReportsHelper
    def generate_basic_report(filename)
        p = Axlsx::Package.new
        wb = p.workbook
        wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Basic Worksheet") do |sheet|
          # Drawing here          
        end
        p.serialize filename 
      end
end
```

Changed post call to /basic_report_post.json and changed action to

```
def basic_report_post
    @config = params[:config]
    @data = params[:data]
    @filename = "#{Rails.root}/public/test.xlsx"
    generate_basic_report(@filename)
    respond_to do |format|
       format.json {
         render json: {name: @filename}
       }          
    end
  end
```

Comment: I wrote `axlsx_rails`. Its response handler tries to render and serve the spreadsheet, so you are right that it would not work.

Comment: What you could have done was use the template handler to render a template to string and write that to a file. That would only be useful if you wanted your spreadsheet code in a template that you could serve either way. [See the axlsx_rails Mailer example](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails#mailers)