# Rails - axlsx_rails, generating xlsx and sending via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, axlsx

What is the best way to send xlsx file via API to frontend and how? 
I'm using **[axlsx_rails](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) gem** for generating report with **xlsx** template.

Options I found are: `json`,`base64`,html.

[Generate .xlsx file and respond filename as json/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689472/axlsx-rails-generate-xlsx-file-and-respond-filename-as-json-html)

---

Rendering xlsx now:

```
 render xlsx: 'status_report', template: 'api/v1/report/status_report.xlsx.axlsx'
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old question but I choosed the base64 option.

```
Axlsx::Package.new do |obj|
    obj.workbook.add_worksheet(name: "Sheet Name") do |sheet|
        # Sheet structure and rows...
    end
    send_data Base64.encode64(obj.to_stream.read), type: "application/xlsx", filename: 'filename.xlsx'
end
```

Just use the `send_data` rails method ([send_data](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data))

Answer (score 0):

you can use `send_file` like this:

```
def export
    Axlsx::Package.new do |obj|  
          obj.workbook.add_worksheet(name: 'worksheet name') do |sheet|
            # Sheet structure and rows...   
          end
        obj.serialize('filename.xlsx')
        send_file File.open('filename.xlsx')
    end
end
```

do not forget to add `rubyzip`, `axlsx`, `axlsx_rails` gems to your `gemfile`.

Answer (score -1):

You should change in application_controller `ActionController::API` to `ActionController::Base`