# How to Download xlsx file using gem "axlsx" and "axlsx_rails" from rails 4 application using AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, xlsx, axlsx

I'm trying to download a xlsx file by using `axlsx` and `axlsx_rails` in a Rails 4 application.

My reports_controller:

```rb
def generate_report
@reports = Report.all
     respond_to do |format|
    format.xlsx {
      response.headers[
        'Content-Disposition'
      ] = "attachment; filename='items.xlsx'"
    }
end
```

Created `generate_report.xlsx.axlsx` file in `app/views/reports/`.

This is the code called when the download button is clicked:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/reports/generate_report',
  data: {
    user_id: user_id
  },
  success: function(response) {
    return console.log('file downloaded');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could convert your xlsx file to `Base64` and then send it.

Have a look at the [send_data](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_data) Rails method to send your `Base64` worksheet.

Source: [Rails - axlsx_rails, generating xlsx and sending via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52824397/rails-axlsx-rails-generating-xlsx-and-sending-via-api)

Comment: thanks for sharing this. but this soluation is not working for me.

Comment: I gave you the method you should use. The source is juste where i got the solution from. I didn't provide you a complete solution, you have to work around it.